# C++ pointer to iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, std, implicit-conversion

I'm looking at some 20 year old C++ code and trying to bring it up to date. The code was last compiled under visual studio 2003 and I am trying to build it with visual studio 2022.

I'm looking at a piece of code right now that doesn't compile. I have an `std::vector<float>`. It looks like a `float*` is passed to a method that requires an iterator. As near as I can figure, there used to be an implicit conversion between pointers and iterators. Does this make any sense? Anybody remember?

Comment: A pointer *is* an iterator, but there is no conversion between pointers and *other* iterators. Never was. `std::vector<float>::iterator` may or may not be the same as `float*`. It it is, there is a trivial conversion. If it is not, there is none. Whether they are the same can change between compiler versions, between release and debug builds, or between Friday and Saturday.

Comment: There are standard library implementations where `std::vector<T>::iterator` was `T*`, so maybe that code got away with being wrong on such implementations.

Comment: This one's not too ugly, but a good reminder of why a company should dust off old code every few years and make sure it's still viable with new tool chains and, where reasonable, follows modern idioms.

Comment: `The code was last compiled under visual studio 2003 and I am trying to build it with visual studio 2022`, good luck, buddy ;)

Comment: Could you please show an example of the code that does not compile?

Answer (score 1):

> I have an `std::vector<float>`. It looks like a `float*` is passed to a method that requires an iterator

A raw pointer is a valid iterator.  Iterators were designed to mimic pointers.

So, if a function takes an `iterator` and is passed a raw pointer, it should compile just fine, in all versions of C++.  A `std::vector<T>` iterator is allowed to be implemented as a raw `T*` pointer.

On the other hand, if a function takes a raw pointer and is passed an `iterator`, there is no guarantee that will compile, since an `iterator` is not required to be implemented as a raw pointer, and never has been.  Are you sure this is not actually the case in your situation?

Comment: About "and never has been": IIRC, VS2003 actually implemented vector iterators as typedefs to pointers. This changed in VS2005. I'd double check it but I don't have access to a VS2003 install right now. This whole situation reeks of "this code has always been broken but worked by accident".

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel "*VS2003 actually implemented vector iterators as typedefs to pointers*" - that is an implementation detail, not a guarantee dictated by the C++ standard. "*this code has always been broken but worked by accident*" - agreed.

Comment: Ah, right, I misread what you wrote.

Answer (score -2):

I think I have seen this before, I drafted the below to show you an example but please don't use this (it's literally s***):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

struct Vector
{
    std::size_t m_size = 0;
    float* m_begin = nullptr;
    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    };
    
    void resize(const std::size_t n, float d = 0)
    {
        m_begin = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            *(m_begin + i) = d;
        m_size = n;
    };
    
    float& operator[](const std::size_t i) const
    {
        assert(i < m_size);
        return *(m_begin + i);
    }
};

void add(float* start, std::size_t size, float shift)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *(start + i) += shift;
}
int main() 
{
    Vector v;
    v.resize(3, 2);
    float& x = v[0];
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    add(v.m_begin, v.m_size, 100);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The `add` takes as input `float*` this also works with matrices i.e. `float**`.

Comment: Huh, where is the `std::vector` in this? How does this answer the question?

Comment: std::vector<float> v;
float* start = &v[0];
This is just an example of how a float* can be passed as arg to a function: responding to "It looks like a float* is passed to a method".

Comment: Yeah, okay, sure, but that's not new information, and it's also not the code you've just shared. More than 3/4 of that code has nothing to do with the problem at hand (it's also, as you have stated, very bad code).

Comment: The individual asking the question is not sure, I have chosen to show the full impl maybe he/she picks something from it and figure out his/her code. No worries in all cases :)

Comment: The "full impl" is code that leaks memory, messes with raw pointers even though it's not needed, doesn't even contain `std::vector` iterator usage despite the question being about `std::vector` iterators, and does not demonstrate the problem. It does not answer the question.

Comment: I mentioned it’s bad code, your comment is not consistent with my answer.